# How do I build Lua 5.2.3 with Unicode identifier support?

Tags: unicode, lua

So I want to have Unicode identifiers in Lua. I followed this guide: http://lua-users.org/wiki/UnicodeIdentifers

But that results in the following error:

```
In file included from lua.h:16:0,
                 from luac.c:15:
luaconf.h:553:27: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before numeric constant
 #define isalnum(zeich) (((0x80&zeich)||isalnum(zeich))&&zeich!=-1)
                           ^
luaconf.h:553:38: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘||’ token
 #define isalnum(zeich) (((0x80&zeich)||isalnum(zeich))&&zeich!=-1)
                                      ^
luaconf.h:553:55: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘&&’ token
 #define isalnum(zeich) (((0x80&zeich)||isalnum(zeich))&&zeich!=-1)
                                                       ^
luaconf.h:550:27: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before numeric constant
 #define isalpha(zeich) (((0x80&zeich)||isalpha(zeich))&&zeich!=-1)
                           ^
luaconf.h:550:38: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘||’ token
 #define isalpha(zeich) (((0x80&zeich)||isalpha(zeich))&&zeich!=-1)
                                      ^
luaconf.h:550:55: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘&&’ token
 #define isalpha(zeich) (((0x80&zeich)||isalpha(zeich))&&zeich!=-1)
                                                       ^
luaconf.h:555:26: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘!’ token
 #define isdigit(zeich) ((!(0x80&zeich)&&isdigit(zeich))&&zeich!=-1)
                          ^
luaconf.h:555:56: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘&&’ token
 #define isdigit(zeich) ((!(0x80&zeich)&&isdigit(zeich))&&zeich!=-1)
                                                        ^
luaconf.h:558:26: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘!’ token
 #define isspace(zeich) ((!(0x80&zeich)&&isspace(zeich))&&zeich!=-1)
                          ^
luaconf.h:558:56: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘&&’ token
 #define isspace(zeich) ((!(0x80&zeich)&&isspace(zeich))&&zeich!=-1)
                                                        ^
 <builtin>: recipe for target 'luac.o' failed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to build Lua 5.2.3 with the modification you did. The first error I get is this one:

```
In file included from luac.c:211:
/usr/include/ctype.h:212:1: error: expected identifier or '('
isalnum(int _c)
```

And the next error are those of your question.

Looking at `luac.c` I saw that `ctype.h` is included at the end of the file (line 211) ; *after* the lua headers. But what you did to build a lua with unicode support was to *redefine* the ctype functions.

You can fix the error by moving the 2 lines starting at line 211:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
```

to the top of the file.

But note: I did try the Lua binary built using these instructions, and it did not accept utf8 identifiers.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is a old question...

I solved this problem, I changed some lines in llex.c.

Solution:

*Look up static int llex function and inside that the loop for(;;)

*And: replace the original default switch in the loop for(;;) by:

```
default: {  /*make lua accept unicode identifiers*/
    if ((((0x80&ls->current)||isalpha(ls->current))&&ls->current!=-1)) {  //lislalpha(ls->current)) {  /* identifier or reserved word? */
      TString *ts;
      do {
        save_and_next(ls);           
      } while ((((0x80&ls->current)||isalnum(ls->current))&&ls->current!=-1)); //lislalnum(ls->current)); /*puts(" <<\n");*/
      ts = luaX_newstring(ls, luaZ_buffer(ls->buff),
                              luaZ_bufflen(ls->buff));
      seminfo->ts = ts;
      if (isreserved(ts))  /* reserved word? */
        return ts->tsv.extra - 1 + FIRST_RESERVED;
      else {
        return TK_NAME;
      }
    }
    else {  /* single-char tokens (+ - / ...) */
      int c = ls->current;
      next(ls);
      return c;
    }
  }
```